# Development of circular function through differential equation

Tags: calculus

Suppose there exists two functions $f(x), g(x)$ which satisfy $$f'(x) = g(x), f(0) = 0, g'(x) = -f(x), g(0) = 1$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is it possible to develop the full theory of circular functions $f(x) = \sin x, g(x) = \cos x$ starting with the given differential equations and initial values? In particular I would like to know if it is possible to establish the existence/uniqueness of such functions $f(x), g(x)$ and the fundamental addition theorems $$f(x + y) = f(x)g(y) + g(x)f(y), g(x + y) = g(x)g(y) - f(x)f(y)$$ An answer based on the basic theorems of elementary calculus would be preferred and in particular I would like to avoid any theorems concerning the solution of a first / second order differential equations.

Comment: May I ask why do you need to do that if you already have $sin(x),cos(x)$ that satisfy the requirements? If the reason is that you want to establish such theory in a domain other than reals or complex, could you clarify the domain?

Comment: @Michael: I want to establish alternative definitions of $\sin x,\cos x$ using these equations for real $x$. It is similar to the case where we can define $e^{x}$ by $f'(x) = f(x), f(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

With just differential calculus, I doubt that you'll have much success in proving the existence of solutions of your system of differential equations.  On the other hand, once you do have 
that existence, the uniqueness is easy.
Note that for any solution $(f,g)$ of the system, $f^2 + g^2$ is constant
since 
 $$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \left(f(x)^2 + g(x)^2\right) = 2 f(x) g(x) - 2 g(x) f(x) = 0 $$

The uniqueness follows from this: if $(f_1, g_1)$ and $(f_2, g_2)$ are solutions with the same initial values $f_1(0) = f_2(0)$, $g_1(0) = g_2(0)$, then $f_3 = f_1 - f_2, g_3 = g_1 - g_2$ is also a solution with initial values
$f_3(0) = g_3(0) = 0$, and then $f_3(x)^2 + g_3(x)^2 = 0$ implying $f_3(x) = g_3(x) = 0$.

Then, for example: if $A(y) = f(x+y) - f(x) g(y) - g(x) f(y)$ and $B(y) = g(x+y) -g(x) g(y) + f(x) f(y)$, then $A(0) = B(0) = 0$ and 
$ A'(y) = B(y)$, $B'(y) = -A(y)$.  So again you get $A(y) = 0$, $B(y) = 0$, and these are your addition theorems.

Comment: This is cool! Maybe it is possible to show the existence by deriving further properties of $f(x), g(x)$ and then guaranteeing their inverse on some interval. Clearly the inverse of circular functions possess algebraic derivatives and it might be possible to show that inverse of $f(x), g(x)$ also have algebraic inverses. Then by integration we can show the existence. The issue in this approach seems to be to find the right intervals where inverse exists and I also don't have access to $\pi$ to think further. Somehow we need to introduce the constant $\pi$.

Comment: Yes, this works.  Let $U(s) = \displaystyle \int_0^s \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ for $-1 \le s \le 1$ (the improper integrals converge for $s=\pm 1$).  Define $\pi/2 = U(1)$.  For $-\pi/2 \le x \le \pi/2$ you can define $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ so that $f(U(s)) = s$ and $g(U(s)) = \sqrt{1-s^2}$.  Then show that $f' = g$ and $g' = -f$ on this interval.

Comment: Of course, that's **integral** calculus, not **differential** calculus.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion caused by "differential" calculus. I will edit the question to use "elementary calculus". On another note I was trying to work my way by studying $f(x)$ to see if it can be inverted and then reach to this integral $U(s)$ you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to look at [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) for that, or [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) if you'd like to stay in the real domain. Specifically, Fourier transform replaces differentiation with multiplication, and that allows you to talk about eigenvalues and eigenvectors of differential operators. After Fourier transform it's an easy exercise to show that eigenspace for your differential equation for a given eigenvalue has dimension 2, and that would prove that $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ span it.